# What does the sign {} mean in this xaml code?

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, escaping, string.format

From [BindingBase.StringFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)

```
<MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} -- Now only {1:C}!">
```

What does the first {} mean? Is it a way to tell that { } which is normally syntax characters in XAML, will be treated as normal character? How exactly do we use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this article on MSDN [{} Escape Sequence / Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx) which says

> The escape sequence ({}) is used so that an open brace ({)can be used as a literal character in XAML.